# JUnit rules TemporaryFolder - Error on Bamboo

Tags: java, junit, bamboo, rule

I wrote some UT with the JUnit Rule TemporaryFolder.
In my UT, I mock a service to return this directory like this:

```
@Rule
public TemporaryFolder folder = new TemporaryFolder();
...
@Test
public void myTest(){
    when(myMock.doSomething()).thenReturn(folder.getRoot());
...
```

Then in the service, folder is used like this:

```
IOFileFilter filtreBasique = new NameFileFilter(tagRCPName + ".xml", IOCase.INSENSITIVE);
FileUtils.listFiles(folder, filtreBasique, TrueFileFilter.TRUE);
```

When I run my UT on my computer, it is all OK, but when I try to run it on Bamboo, I have this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter 'directory' is not a directory
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.listFiles(FileUtils.java:358)
```

I cannot figure out why...

Comment: How are you passing `folder` into the class that calls `FileUtils.listFiles`? I assume there are multiple tests being run in Bamboo. Is the class under test part of a context? Is Bamboo reusing this context and thereby getting a previous instance of the class under test?

Comment: `folder` is returned by the mock of my UT. And the class is not a part of a context...
`when(myMock.doSomething()).thenReturn(folder.getRoot());`

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. The point is, how is the mock provided to the class under test? Somehow you are getting `directory` as the folder which is not something `TemporaryFolder` would provide as the root. So somehow your class under test is not using the mock or the mock is not being reset between tests.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I found my mistake and it was nothing really serious...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found my mistake... 
It has nothing to do with the Rule JUnit...

It was when I tried to list the files in my directories I had a structure like [TEMP_REPO]\test\test and the separators where hard written. So I replace them by `System.getProperty("file.separator")` and everything went fine.

Hope this could help someone...